# Swift textView align with english and arabic languages

Tags: swift, textview, alignment, arabic

My project work with English and Arabic Language,

I've used YLTextView lib when writting: https://github.com/liyong03/YLTextView

but, when i set text to new textView, it's alignment is wrong.
this is my text project: [link to mytextProject](http://www.mediafire.com/file/kuwwg6hjdn65xj6/ArabicTextView.zip)

My issue is how to show text in textview2 with alignment as same as writing in textview1

AnyOne help this, please.

[image]

Comment: What is your issue ?

Comment: Now I do know what do you want. So I tried to search but there is nothing from which we can find that this word r from arabic language. So I think it is like too hard to do

Comment: My issue is how to show text in textview2 with alignment as same as writing in textview1

Comment: Yeah, I know your problem, now there is only one solution like you manually set the alignment of textview then It will be as expected

Comment: yeah, i'm trying, thks for your care.

Comment: any luck with this?